# "Either A and B is open, then A + B is open" (typo sense-making, Stein Shakarchi Real Analysis)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please advise about the most reasonable way to read this statement. My interpretations are below.

The authors do not define the set operation A + B; I assume A + B = $A \cup B$.

Their statement "Show that if either A and B is open, then A + B is open" is incorrect unless it should read "both A and B are open."

Counterexample when only A is open and B is not: Let $A=B_1(O)\subset \mathbb{R}^2,\ B=\overline{B_1(2)}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Then there exist points in B which are not interior points of $A\cup B$ (e.g. (3,0), a boundary point of B).

Comment: $A+B$ is defined as $\{a+b \mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.

Comment: And if $A+B=\{a+b \mid a \in A,\ b \in B\}$?

Comment: Thank you both, this works. Can either of you please cite why this is a reasonable interpretation? Just so I can cover my butt when I turn in my homework

Comment: That  is  the  $\mathbb  definition  $ of  $A+B$ , meaning  that  is  what  $A+B$  means .$A+B=\{a+b | a\in A, b\in B \}$ .  No $\mathbb  why's .$.  In  euclidean  spaces ,  this  can  be  seen  as  translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the notation $A + B$ doesn't denote the union, but the Minkowski sum of the two sets:
$$A + B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}.$$

Comment: Great, thanks for providing the name of the sum! It reminded me that there was an asterisked section which I had not yet read, in which the Minkowski sum was defined.. seems every time I assume the author has been negligent, it turns out I am the guilty one.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A,B\subseteq G$ be subsets of a topological group (for example $G=\mathbb R^n$).

We have
$$A+B=\bigcup_{b\in B}A+b.$$

If $A$ is open then so is $A+x$ for all $x\in G$. So $A+B$ is a union of open sets, hence open.

In case we know that $A+B$ is open we don't know if one of $A$, $B$ is open. That is already the case in $\mathbb R$. Take for example $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\mathbb Z$. Then $A+B=\mathbb R$ is open but none of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are subsets of an additive group), the we can define $A+B:=\{\,a+b:a\in A,b\in B\,\}$. With this definition and if we talk about subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, $A+B$ is open if at least one of $A,B$ is open (being the union of open sets)